# How to optimize parse data flow algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing

I need to implement some abstract protocol client-server conversation parsing library with C++. I don't have file containing the whole client-server conversation, but have to parse it on the fly. I have to implement following interface:

```
class parsing_class
{
  public:
  void on_data( const char* data, size_t len );
  //other functions
  private:
  size_t pos_;// current position in the data flow
  bool first_part_parsed_;
  bool second_part_parsed_;
  //... some more bool markers or something like vector< bool >
};
```

The data is passed to my class through `on_data` function. Data chunk length varies from one call to another. I know protocol's packet format and know how conversation should be organized, so I can judge by current `pos_` whether i have enough data to parse `Nth` part. 
Now the implementation is like following:

```
void parsing_class::on_data( const char* data, size_t len )
{
   pos_ += len;
   if( pos > FIRST_PART_SIZE and !first_part_parsed_ )
     parse_first_part( data, len );
   if( pos > SECOND_PART_SIZE and !second_part_parsed_ )
     parse_second_part( data, len );
   //and so on..  
}
```

What I want is some tips how to optimize this algorithm. Maybe to avoid these numerous `if` ( `on_data` may be called very many times and each time it will have to go through all switches ).

Comment: Looks like your on_data will be called twice with same data? otherwise you don't need this logic, right?

Comment: It is called by client many times, each time with the new chunk of data, which i add to internal storage and parse. When i decide that i have enogh information, i call user supplied callback to infrom user that the work is done.

Comment: first_part_parsed_/second_part_parsed_ are redundant? can tell the step from pos?

Comment: No, they are not. Because the very first chunk may be large enough to contain two or more parts so i can't rely only on pos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all those `bool` and `pos_`, as they seem to only keep the state of what of the conversation has passed so that you can continue with the next part.

How about the following: write yourself a parse function for each of the parts of the conversation

```
bool parse_part_one(const char *data) {
    ... // parse the data
    next_fun = parse_part_two;
    return true;
}
bool parse_part_two(const char *data) {
    ... // parse the data
    next_fun = parse_part_thee;
    return true;
}
...
```

and in your class you add a pointer to the current parse function, starting at one.  Now, in `on_data` all you do is to call the next parse function

```
bool success = next_fun(data);
```

Because each function sets the pointer to the next parse function, the next call of `on_data` will invoke the next parse function automatically.  No tests required of where in the conversation you are.

If the value of `len` is critical (which I assume it would be) then pass that along as well and return `false` to indicate that the part could not be parsed (don't update `next_fun` in that case either).